# I have a problem python recursive function

Tags: python

So I did this function to calculate the sequence 3*1-3*2.....-3*n

```
def rec(n):
    if(n==1):
        return 3
    else:
        return (-rec(3*n)+rec(3*(n-1)))
x=rec(3)
print(x)
```

After your comments I came closer to the answer

def rec(n):
if(n==1):
return 1
else:
return -(3*n)+(3*rec(n-1))
x=rec(3)
print(x)

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Can you please explain more what you are trying to do? Also, a minimal reproducible example of the code will help us.

Comment: here your n value is increasing from 2 to infinity, you need to add a condition to exit if value reached at that point, for eg `if n>100: return 3`

Comment: I want to calculate the sum of this sequence 3*1 - 3*2 - 3*3 .... - 3*n using recursive function

Comment: Please read [ask]. You will know more about what is actually happening than just "it doesn't work" so you should take the time to include all that relevant information in your post

Comment: I did include the sequence I tried to solve

Answer (score 0):

```
def rec(n):
    if(n == 1):
       return 3
    else:
      return - 3 * n + rec(n-1)

x=rec(2)
print(x)
```